# Can you say "the 2 keyboards are identical except that the y and z are in different places"

Tags: word-usage

Is this correct use of the words - can it be said like this?

The 2 keyboards are exactly the same except the y and z keys are in different places?

Can you say something is exactly the same except...

Comment: *Can you say something is exactly the same except...* Yes, you can.

Comment: @Greybeard  It's a six-year-old question, I doubt that the OP even recalls asking it. To the Closevoters: I'm not sure what kind of research the OP could have done or is now expected to do in order to keep their Q open.

Comment: Look on it as a help for anyone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ...except [that] the y and z keys are [**transposed**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/transpose)

*Cause (two or more things) to **exchange** places* (oxforddictionaries)

(As only *two* keys are in different places, they must have *swapped/exchanged* locations.)